# onchange event to input and select from form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I would like to know how it is possible to add an onchange event in a form and search for select and inputs when they are changed as in the code below but in pure javascript.

```
$("form#formulario-simular-mensalidade").on('change', ['input', 'select'], function () {
    //getFaturamentosByTipoServico($("select#tipo-simulacao").val());
    simularMensalidade();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener()`. Within the listener function, `event.target` will be the specific element that was changed.

```
document.querySelector("form#formulario-simular-mensalidade").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // prevent it from bubbling out to other elements
    var changed_element = event.target;
    // now you can use things like changed_element.value, changed_element.name, etc.
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Also to note, you should add `event.target.name` and `event.target.value` to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't forget something it's something like this:

```js
const setup = () => {
    const form = document.querySelector('#formulario-simular-mensalidade');
  form.addEventListener('change', onChange)
}

const onChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
  
  if(target.nodeName === 'INPUT' || target.nodeName === 'SELECT') {
    //const value = target.id === 'tipo-simulacao' ? target.value : undefined;
    simularMensalidade();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```